# What is the helper function for "lowercase" when writing an Angular schematic template?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-schematics

I'm working on building a simple angular schematic template following a [tutorial here](https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/total-guide-to-custom-angular-schematics-5c50cf90cdb4). All going well. This tutorial uses a helper function (`dasherize`) to convert the file name from `AwesomeWrap` to `hello-awesome-wrap`.

```
hello-__name@dasherize__
```

I want to change this functionality in my own implementation to simply ensure file names are lower case, so `AwesomeWrap` should be `awesomewrap`.

This functionality doesn't seem well documented though (or not that I can find) and I can't find a list of available functions for this. I tried creating a file `view-__name@lowercase__.ts` but `lowercase` didn't seem an available function.

When I run `schematics .:sensor --name=test`, I get the error message:

> Error: Pipe "lowercase" is not defined.

So what is the correct syntax for this? Is there a list of available transforms that can be performed in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently **no** `lowercase` in the Angular Schematics Devkit package.

You can see all the supported functions here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/angular_devkit/core/src/utils/strings.ts

If you need a lowercase function you can open a Pull Request for this file and add it.

Answer (score 0):

I can only image that they transform `dasherize__` to `require('dasherize')(__)`. Where `__` is obviously the name of the file. Soo, I guess we need to find a package which does lowercase for you:

```
npm install lower-case
```

And I guess you can then use this as:

```
view-__name@lower-case__.ts
```

Comment: Added the error message if that's any help. It seems to be looking for a pipe but lowercase is the correct pipe so I'm not sure what I'm missing

Comment: @Liam Aw, unfortunately! Was worth a shot :D. There should be a way though, to extend the angular devkit. Otherwise I believe it's quite limited

Comment: Yeah again, makes good sense. I might just submit a PR, it's seems an obvious piece of missing functionality and really simple to implement

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late answer.

In your template file(example: `./files/__name@dasherize__.component.ts`)file just use `string.toLowerCase()`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: "<%= name.toLowerCase() %>",
  template: `
  `,
})
export class <%= classify(name)%>Component {

}
```

If you want to use it like dasherize, go to index.ts

```
export function mySchematics(_options: Schema): Rule {
  return (tree: Tree, _context: SchematicContext) => {
    const sourceTemplates = url('./files');

    const sourceParametrizedTemplates = apply(sourceTemplates, [
      template({
        ..._options,
        ...strings,
        tolowercase
      })
    ]);

    return mergeWith(sourceParametrizedTemplates)(tree, _context);
  };
}

export function tolowercase(value: string): string {
  return value.toLowerCase();
}
```

Then you can use like in folder or file name:

`__name@tolowercase__component.ts`

also use in template like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: "<%= tolowercase(name) %>",
  template: `
  `,
})
export class <%= classify(name)%>Component {

}
```